# parsing date and time in java

Tags: java, parsing, datetime

I have Time format in (yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm+0:0000)..i need to convert this format to mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm am/pm using java program...any one help me to do this..thanx in advance...

Comment: so you have a `String`, and you want to transform it to another string?

Comment: Can you explain more? Where does the string come from? XML? Where does it go to? Swing GUI?

Answer (score 11):

Try something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm+s:SSSS");
Date date = format.parse(dateString);
format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a");
dateString = format.format(date);
```

Comment: In the second format, it takes the current (local) timezone. Supply an own if you don't want the default one.

Answer (score 5):

Here’s the modern answer. `SimpleDateFormat` was the right answer in 2011 when the question was asked, but it isn’t any longer. The old classes turned out to be troublesome, so at long last their replacements came out early in 2014.

I was a bit puzzled about a couple of details in your formats.

- `yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm+0:0000` looks a bit like an ISO 8601 offset date-time, but then `+0:0000` should be the offset from UTC. I am speculating that it may have been intended as an offset in `h:mmss` format, but it is non-standard and nothing I have ever seen elsewhere.
- You seem to be asking for am/pm in lowercase. This is non-standard too and not built-in with the standard classes.

I suggest:

```
    DateTimeFormatter sourceFormat
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'+0:0000'");
    DateTimeFormatter targetFormat
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String sourceTime = "2017-07-05T20:31+0:0000";
    String convertedTime = LocalDateTime.parse(sourceTime, sourceFormat)
            .format(targetFormat)
            .toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

    System.out.println(convertedTime);
```

This prints

```
07-05-2017 08:31 pm
```

I found it safest just to require literal `+0:0000` in the input, not trying to interpret it. For producing `pm` in lowercase, I converted the whole string to lowercase after formatting. There is a different trick [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42466448/5772882).

An attempt to be more flexible with hours, minutes and seconds in the offset and make sense of them could be:

```
    sourceTime = sourceTime.replaceFirst("(\\d:\\d{2})(\\d{2})$", "0$1:$2");
    String convertedTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(sourceTime)
            .format(targetFormat)
            .toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

The `replaceFirst` converts `0:0000` to `00:00:00`, which when preceeded by `+` or `-` conforms with an ISO 8601 offset. This will work with other offsets too (as long as hour is one digit; you may want to try both one and two digits in turn). In the concrete code we are still ignoring the offset when formatting, but it could be used for other purposes if desired.

`DateTimeFormatter`, `LocalDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime` are part of JSR-310. They are built in in Java 8 and later. You may use them in Java 6 and 7 too through the [*ThreeTen Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). There is also a specific edition of the backport for Android, [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score 2):

Look at `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` - you'll need two instances, one for parsing, one for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

See the working example with this code snippet:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class DateTimeAMPM {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

DateFormat inputDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm+s:SSSS");
Date date = inputDateFormatter.parse("2011-11-11T22:33+0:400");
String outputDateFormatter = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss a";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(outputDateFormatter);
System.out.println("Date: " + sdf.format(date));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Paulo and morja say or just use String.substring() since your parsing-requirements are very simple.

Comment: The OP asked for `am` or `pm`. I don’t think it’s feasible to obtain those through substringing?

Answer (score 0):

You should create Data object from your String -> use appropriate class (e.g. [SimpleDataFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)) and then print it by using another format.